# Create visual states through code - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visualstates

I have a simple question. Can Visual states be defined through code for a button in WP8? We can change visual states through code using GoTo function but can visual states be defined in the code behind?

Suppose on the click of a button I need to change the image of it? Is there any method by which you can change the background through visual states.

Comment: Yes you can create a VisualState for a control You should add the VisualStateGroup into the VisualStateGroupManager.VisualStateGroups attached property of the Control.

Comment: It's unusual to do that at runtime though. Why not just create a button control that sets the background directly?